# How can be fixed bootstrap divs in same line when screen makes zoom?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, html-table

I have two divs each one has a table. Nn 100% zoomed, they are seemed normal.
When I make the zoom as 150%, naturally, the second table is shifting in the next line.

I'd like placed two divs in the same line for all zoom options. It can be a scrollbar for each divs but I want that it never shift in the next line. 
Is it possible?

These are my code scraps:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    </head>
    <div class="row table-responsive col-md-12">
            <div class="col-md-4">

                <table class="table">
                    <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Colum 1</th>
                        <th>Colum 2</th>
                        <th>Colum 3</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr >
                        <td>Row 1 - Field1</td>
                        <td>Row 1 - Field2</td>
                        <td>Row 1 - Field3</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr >
                        <td>Row 2 - Field1</td>
                        <td>Row 2 - Field2</td>
                        <td>Row 2 - Field3</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr >
                        <td>Row 3 - Field1</td>
                        <td>Row 3 - Field2</td>
                        <td>Row 3 - Field3</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody></table>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <table class="table">
                    <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Colum 1</th>
                        <th>Colum 2</th>
                        <th>Colum 3</th>
                        <th>Colum 4</th>
                        <th>Colum 5</th>
                        <th>Colum 6</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr >
                        <td>Row 1 - Field1</td>
                        <td>Row 1 - Field2</td>
                        <td>Row 1 - Field3</td>
                        <td>Row 1 - Field4</td>
                        <td>Row 1 - Field5</td>
                        <td>Row 1 - Field6</td>
                    </tr>

                </tbody></table>
            </div>
        </div>    
</html>
```

and my screenshots:

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to adjust your HTML code to the following:

```
 <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
            <div class="table-responsive">
                <table></table>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-8">
            <div class="table-responsive">
                <table class="table"></table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: heeeey, this is the what I exactly need!! Many thanks!